# How to debug AvroConsumer in confluent kafka?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-python, confluent-kafka-python

I'm trying to read Kafka from python but recieve message is None , No errors in CLI.
I'm using port forwarding to destination host via putty, and than test ports over telnet - it work's fine.
Moreover, i'm using kafkacat on Debian (WSL) and it work's fine!

```
kafkacat -C -b localhost:9092 -t topic1 -p 0 -o beginning -s avro -r http://localhost:28081
```

I'm using PyCharm, my code is below in the text. How do I debug?

```
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroConsumer
from confluent_kafka import TopicPartition
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import SerializerError

topics = ['topic1', 'topic2']
c = AvroConsumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest',
    'schema.registry.url': 'http://localhost:28081',
    'api.version.request': True
})

c.subscribe(topics)
tp = TopicPartition(topics[0], 0, 0)
c.assign([tp])

while True:
    try:
        msg = c.poll(1)

    except SerializerError as e:
        print("Message deserialization failed for {}: {}".format(msg, e))
        break

    if msg is None:
        print('Message None')
        continue

    if msg.error():
        print("AvroConsumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
        continue

    print(msg.value())

c.close()
```

as

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'll do is make sure that messages are coming on your topics using the `kafka-avro-console-consumer` tool.

Then in your app you can try to increase the log level:

```
c = AvroConsumer({
    # ... your config here
    'log_level': 7,
    'debug': 'all',
})
```

You can see the different parameters here: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

But I believe your issue has to to with the way you are assigning partitions. If you use `subscribe` than partitions are assigned to your consumer automatically by the cluster. You can add a call back when you subscribe to you can see which partitions are assigned to your consumer, but you shouldn't have to do it your self. See https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.subscribe

Comment: Thanks for debug string! 
I add comment to strin 
`#tp = TopicPartition(topics[0], 0, 0)
#c.assign([tp])`
and now i have debug message, where i see offset 6 msg, but i don't understand why it's not worked. [link_bug_text](https://pastebin.com/8U84K1qZ) . @Arthur, may you help?